# Get LookupEdit's instance of gridControl

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have reference to a `LookUpEdit` but I want to access it's `GridControl` object. We use the gridControlObject for exporting to excel.

I have found a previous question that is quite similar:

[How to get instance of the GridControl in LookupEdit (Devexpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612435/how-to-get-instance-of-the-gridcontrol-in-lookupedit-devexpress)

and the edited part of the answer does work, except only after the user has opened the LookUpEdit.

Is there any way accessing it **without the user opening the drop down**?

Failing that does anyone have a suggestion on how to force an open and close from code? Obviously `LookUpEdit1.ShowPopup()` will open it, but how do I wait for it to load?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out to make the popup open and close, would still be interested in a more intelligent solution!

in XAML code I adedd a PopupOpened property for the lookUpEdit

inside the popUpopened Method I raise an event.

So I register an interest in the popUpOpened Event, open the dropdown and close it again on receiving the event. Not overly proud of the solution but it does seem to work fine.